# On click function uncheck other radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have given code

```
<ul id="payment-method-fields">
  <li id="paypal">
    <label>
      <input checked="checked" id="order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_5" name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]" type="radio" value="5">
      Test Paypal

    </label>
  </li>
  <li id="adyen">
    <label>
      <input id="order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_4" name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]" type="radio" value="4">
      Ali Pay
    </label>
  </li>
  <li id="adyen_encrypted">
    <label>
      <input id="order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_16" name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]" type="radio" value="16">
      credit card

    </label>
  </li>
  <li id="cod" >
    <label>
      <input id="cash-on-delivery" name="cod" type="radio" value="">
      Cash on Delivery
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

my requirement is when click on other li i.e on Cash on Delivery then paypal gets unchecked. Please guide me how I will write this jquery.

Comment: I think that is you wrap it inside a `<form>` tag the browser will automatically do that

Comment: Why is paypal/cash not in the same radio group?

Comment: All list items should have the same name and Cash on Delivery does not.

Comment: @Glubus I believe that `cod` does not equal `order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#cash-on-delivery').on('change', function(){
    $('input[name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]"]')
                                                          .prop('checked', !this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is:

```
$('#payment-method-fields :input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(e) {
   if (this.id == 'cash-on-delivery') {
      $('#payment-method-fields').find('input[type="radio"]:not(#' + this.id + ')').prop('checked', false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply give them the same name for all input tags
Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="group_name" />
```

This ensures only one is selected at any time.

Answer (score 1):

You can give all inputs a same class for example

class="radio_button"

And then you can add code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.radio_button').on('click',function(){
        $('.radio_button').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).prop('checked','checked');
    })
}
```

Comment: this works if you can`t afford same name for all radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The last `input` has a different name `<input id="cash-on-delivery" name="cod" type="radio" value="">` than the others so when you check it the others won't automatically uncheck. Give it the same name and it will work fine.

Here is an [**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/QyvgNZ?editors=101) of it working.

Code:

```
<ul id="payment-method-fields">
  <li id="paypal">
    <label>
      <input checked="checked" id="order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_5" name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]" type="radio" value="5">
      Test Paypal

    </label>
  </li>
  <li id="adyen">
    <label>
      <input id="order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_4" name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]" type="radio" value="4">
      Ali Pay
    </label>
  </li>
  <li id="adyen_encrypted">
    <label>
      <input id="order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_16" name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]" type="radio" value="16">
      credit card

    </label>
  </li>
  <li id="cod" >
    <label>
      <input id="cash-on-delivery" name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]" type="radio" value="">
      Cash on Delivery
    </label>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check/uncheck a checkbox, use the attribute checked and alter that. With jQuery you can do:

```
    //$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', true); // Checks it
    //$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it

    $('#cash-on-delivery').on('change', function(){
    $('input[name="order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]"]').attr('checked',true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the property 'checked' from the input-elements with the jQuery [removeProp](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) function. For your example create two functions and call them in the onClick trigger of your input-elements:

```
function uncheckTop3() {
  $('#order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_5').removeProp('checked');
  $('#order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_4').removeProp('checked');
  $('#order_payments_attributes__payment_method_id_16').removeProp('checked');
}

function uncheckCashOnDelivery() {
  $('#cash-on-delivery').removeProp('checked');
}
```

Here a [jfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/pwwquv5z/1/) to your example.